# A confusion regarding Affine spaces

Tags: affine-geometry

Take an Affine space $\Bbb{A}$ over the field $K$.

How would you determine the points satisfying any polynomial $f(x)$? If there is no fixed origin, points can be given names with reference to ANY point in the Affine space! Hence, it seems to me that there would be multiple loci of $f(x)$, depending upon the refernce point (read "origin").

Comment: Affine spaces in algebraic geometry should not be confused with affine spaces in linear algebra.